# Splitting text by a Unicode script in Python

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have some text like this:

এর জন্য বুদ্ধির (Reason) প্রয়োজন নেই, প্রয়োজন নিজের

The language is Bengali (apart from the one English word of course).

I would like to obtain a list of Bengali words in the text (ie a word tokenization problem). Bengali has a Unicode range 0980 to 09FF. There is also a \p{Bengali} script (don't know how to use it). Here's what I have:

```
import re
Pattern = re.compile(r'\[\u0980-\u09FF]+')
Words = split(Pattern, Text)
```

Which is not working. How can I get this to work? I'd also prefer to use \p{Bengali} if possible, rather than the explicit Unicode range.

Comment: Just a check, are you on Python 3.x or 2.x? Makes a big difference with Unicode.

Comment: When using raw literal strings (`r''`) for regular expressions, you don't need to escape your square brackets.

Comment: Yes exactly. Just found that out. Thanks.

Comment: @MattH: This has nothing to do with raw strings. In normal strings, you shouldn't escape the brackets either since `\[` would be translated to `\\[`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't yet understand the Unicode script properties like `\p{...}`.

Your version should work after you remove the backslash that's escaping the bracket, and by not using `split()` but `findall()` (you didn't even use `re.split()` but I guess that was just a typo).

Also, since you're not using Python 3 as you stated in your recent comment, you probably need to use the `re.UNICODE` option and make sure that `text` is in fact a `Unicode` string.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(ur'[\u0980-\u09FF]+', re.UNICODE)
words = re.findall(pattern, text)
```

Comment: ``CapWords`` is generally used for class names in Python, [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends ``lowercase_with_underscores`` for local variables.

Comment: @Lattyware: Thanks, I was just about to comment on that.

Comment: I tried: SimpleWordTokenizer = re.compile(r'[\u0980-\u09FF]+', re.UNICODE)
    Temp = re.findall(SimpleWordTokenizer, text) Unfortunately it gives me the English words instead of the Bengali ones!

Comment: Ah! I got it to work by ur'[\u0980-\u09FF]+'. Apparently that 'u' in front made the difference.

Comment: Ah, of course, I overlooked that. Great to hear it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alternate `regex` library by installing it using pip:

```sh
pip3 install regex
```

and use the `\p{ScriptName}` pattern to find the script you're looking for:

```py
import regex
t = "এর জন্য বুদ্ধির (Reason) প্রয়োজন নেই, প্রয়োজন নিজের"
t = regex.findall(r"[\p{Bengali}]+", t)
print(t)
```

More on the regex module [here](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)

Answer (score -1):

you can just split by white spaces:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = 'এর জন্য বুদ্ধির (Reason) প্রয়োজন নেই, প্রয়োজন নিজের'
>>> re.split('\s', x)
['\xe0\xa6\x8f\xe0\xa6\xb0', '\xe0\xa6\x9c\xe0\xa6\xa8\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\xaf', '\xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa7\x81\xe0\xa6\xa6\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\xa7\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb0', '(Reason)', '\xe0\xa6\xaa\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\xb0\xe0\xa6\xaf\xe0\xa6\xbc\xe0\xa7\x8b\xe0\xa6\x9c\xe0\xa6\xa8', '\xe0\xa6\xa8\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x87,', '\xe0\xa6\xaa\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\xb0\xe0\xa6\xaf\xe0\xa6\xbc\xe0\xa7\x8b\xe0\xa6\x9c\xe0\xa6\xa8', '\xe0\xa6\xa8\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\x9c\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\xb0']
```

Comment: This doesn't achieve what is wanted, and in that case, an re is overkill, why not just do x.split()?

Comment: I was thinking of splitting 'by Bengali' as described, since it would automatically get rid of all English characters, punctuation marks, etc.

Comment: True, didn't read it thoroughly enough and now for some reason I can't delete my answer.